# Password protected xls file using DynamicReports in Java

Tags: java, passwords, jasper-reports, export-to-excel, dynamic-reports

I am trying to generate a password protected xls file using *DynamicReports 4.1* which is internally using *JasperReports 6*.

Here is the code:

```
JasperXlsExporterBuilder xlsBuilder = export
                    .xlsExporter(report);
            if (null != password) {
                xlsBuilder.setPassword(password);
            }
```

Problem is that it created only readonly protected file. Password is not asked for opening the file. I have tried with Apache POI as well, same thing would happen (as JasperXlsExporter using Apache POI only I guess). I have a requirement of open protected xls and not read only protection.

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not achievable, since XLS workbooks encryption is not yet supported in Apache POI library, as you already noticed.

Comment: Do you suggest any other Java API which provides this ? I just want to double check the facts before declaring open password protection for xls files "non-achievable" using Java

Comment: As far as I know, there are no open source Java APIs that provide XLS workbook encryption. Apache POI is the most known and largely used, another one was JExcelApi. There are some other libraries you could consider for this feature, but they are not open source. See for instance JExcel or EasyXLS.